# Convert JMeter test cases to LoadRunner with VUs

Tags: jmeter, loadrunner

I have several `JMeter` test cases, which should be converted to `HP LoadRunner`. There are virtual users too, so these should be compatible with test.

Comment: Just follow https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-run-JMeter-test-in-LoadRunner-Performance-Center-12-55/ba-p/1619836#.Wtx2SXXwazc

Comment: @MichaelDurrant : How can I use licensed virtual users in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking (there is no question) but starting 12.55 you can run JMeter tests without converting directly from the Controller

Comment: How can I use virtual users after I imported JMeter script?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can use the following blog post: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/How-to-run-JMeter-test-in-LoadRunner-Performance-Center-12-55/ba-p/1619836#.Wt7fJ4hubqY

Comment: or this help article https://admhelp.microfocus.com/lr/en/12.56/help/WebHelp/Content/Controller/jmeter_run_test.htm